# Django 1.9 forms include is not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Im trying to change the **view of admin** though I try to modify admin with the **help of forms**, I dont see any changes and end up with all the fields

My model consisting primarily of email and name

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField('name',max_length=120, blank=True, null=True,)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('time',auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self): #Python 3.3 is __str__
        return self.email
```

My form

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
class META:
    model= SignUp
    fields=['email']
```

Im trying to add the form in **admin** so that only **email** is displayed

My admin, I'm trying to **include only email field**

```
class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['full_name', 'timestamp', 'updated']
    form = SignUpForm
    admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

**But I end up with both email and name displayed. I only wanted email to be shown in admin page**

[image]

Any help is much appriciated......Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the indentation on meta is a copy/paste error in your question, but that needs to be indented in your class, but also, it shouldn't all be capitalised

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= SignUp
        fields=['email']
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ...I did change the indentation, but this the problem exists.....

Comment: @spidy - I didn't understand your comment, does the problem persist? have you changed the "eta" to lowercase?..

Comment: @spidy You should also unindent the `admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)`

Comment: Hey thanks.......it worked......It was the problem with META only, it should have been Meta...